# Im unable to login to firebase with a registered email. How to fix the error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two Viewcontrollers. One to register new users and one to log in. If I use the register view controller to sign up with a new email and password everything works fine and my users info is saved in Firebase. I can log in and see it from the firebase dash.

But when I go to my log in view controller and attempt to log in with an already created account. I get this error every time. Any idea how to fix this would be a huge help. Thanks.

The code below is my log in view controller code.

This is the error:
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "The email address is badly formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is badly formatted., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL}

The email I type in is the exact same.

import UIKit
import Firebase

class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
//this function reads Firebase data and if an email and password matches it will login and send to home screen of the app
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            if let e = error { // need to put something in to let userk now there was an error
                print(e)
            } else { // navigate to home view controller
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logintoHomeViewController", sender: self)
            }

        }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and verify the value of the `email` variable is what you think it is.

Comment: Doing this helped me fix the issue by showing me what was going on. I'll remember this for next time. Thanks